# Moving Website From CMS

Tags: html, cms, phpmyadmin

I have recently had a website created for me by an IT company. The problem is that i am being charged extortant amounts of money to change minor things. They have charged me to a create a small CMS system, but it is overly simple and gives me very little control.

I want to move my website to a new host so that I have full control of it.

Can someone please explain the process i would have to go through in order to achieve this?

NB: I have experience working with SQL, phpMyAdmin, HTML, CSS etc.

Any and all help is much appreciated.. :)

Comment: what kind of site is this? Have you considered moving to something like Wordpress?

Comment: I am considering wordpress.. but i have no idea what CMS they are currently using.. i am being told it is an "in house" built CMS so i am wondering how i would do this..

Comment: @lbz well, if it's a custom CMS you'll need to put the data into wordpress manually. Unless you know how to write a converter for WP

Comment: thats something im willing to do as they are charging me close to £100 for small thing i want to change lol.. ridicolous..
would it just be a case of changing the html files to point to new addresses and then uploading them?

Comment: If you own the domain name, you should be able to point it to a new host. Depends on whether you have access to your domain name.

Comment: i thinks thats restricted also.. although i think i need to to sme further enquiries.. thank you for your responses though :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have full control over your DNS records, then you can create a subdomain (`test.mydomain.com`) and point the A record to a new hosting company.  Here you can build your new website (a CMS is always a good option, will make for faster development).  When the new site is done and ready, change the A record of `mydomain.com` and/or `www.mydomain.com` to the IP address of the new hosting company and then switch the rest over.

Comment: the thing is, they are restricting my access to the website as it is, although i think i would be able to get a copy of all the html files and stuff.. would it just be a case of pointing links in the new direction before uploading them at the new host?

Comment: There are tools that allow you to grab everything from a website, but all you will grab is the content in the form of HTML. This will probably work for you.  You can navigate to each page and grab the contents.  I will see if I can find the name of such a utility.

Comment: The primary concern is the domain name.,  If you do not have full control over the DNS records, the it will be a little harder to manage.

Comment: hopefully they will allow me access to the domain that i pay for..
thank you for your help Leons :)
if you could name one of these utilities it will be very useful :)

Comment: GetLeft is a utility that will pull down a website's content.